# Overwritten EEPROM

Tags: teensy, eeprom, array

I have a problem with the Teensy, its EEPROM and another Array.

My program contains two Arrays, the first one is a 128x4 long Array, the other one a 2560x2 double Array. The first Array is meant to be written to the EEPROM once a certain time (=number of loops) is reached. The other Array is meant to be written to an SD-Card or just the terminal, can't deiced yet.

My problem is that whenever I uncomment the save()-function the first 17 data-quadruples in the EEPROM get somehow overwritten by random data. Always the first 17 with would be the first 68 numbers or 272 byte.

I have tried renameing the save()-function, but the onlything that works for now is to comment the function in the loop()-function out so that it won't be called at all. I even have enough RAM left, the Arduino IDE tells me I am using about 73% of the RAM for variables.

Could it be that be creating more variables somewhere else the Teensy overwrites the Array for the EEPROM? But than again why doesn't that happen if I don't write into the everything-Array?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Greetings,

John

PS: Please excuse my not perfect English for it's not my native language.

```
//Includes
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

elapsedMillis looptime = 0; //time for each loop in ms
int loopnumber = 0; //number of loops
elapsedMillis overalltime = 0; //overalltime in ms
const int iterationtime = 25; //time for each loop in ms

//EEPROM
//Deklarations
int nsd = 0; //counter for saving into eepromArray
const int maxArrayrows = 128; //Max number of row in eepromArray
int iArray = 0; //Number of used rows in eepromArray
long eepromArray[128][4]; //Array for EEPROM-storage
bool writtentoEEPROM = false;
double everything[2560][2]; //Big Araay with a pair of numbers of each loop

// Some more variables
double z, zpunkt, alpha, angle;

void setup() {
 // Just inititialing stuff, nothing to do with the Arrays
}

void loop() {
  //Calculating more stuff

  ++nsd;
  if (nsd >= 20) {
    WritetoArray();
  }

  save(loopnumber);

  ++loopnumber;

  looptime = 0;
}


//********************************************************
//
// Save Data in Array. If full write into EEPROM
//
// long: 4 byte
// Storeage needed for each quadruple: 4*4 byte = 16 byte
// EEPROM-size: 2 kibyte
// Max number of quadruples: 2048 byte / 16 byte = 128
// Quadrupels per second: 2
// Max time: 128 / 2 = 64 s
//
//********************************************************
void WritetoArray() {
  int scale = 10000;
  long zArray = (long)(scale * z);
  long zpunktArray = (long)(scale * zpunkt);
  long alphaArray = (long)(scale * alpha);
  long angleArray = (long)(scale * angle);
  if (iArray < maxArrayrows) {
    eepromArray[iArray][0] = zArray;
    eepromArray[iArray][1] = zpunktArray;
    eepromArray[iArray][2] = alphaArray;
    eepromArray[iArray][3] = angleArray;
    ++iArray;
  }
  else {
    if (writtentoEEPROM == false) {
      WritetoEEPROM();
      writtentoEEPROM = true;
    }
    while(true){
      for(int n = 0; n < 2560; ++n){
        Serial.printf("%f, %f\n", everything[n][0], everything[n][1]);
      }
      Serial.println("----------");
    }
  }
  nsd = 0;
}


//********************************************************
//
// Write Data to EEPROM
//
//********************************************************
void WritetoEEPROM() {
  byte data;
  int adress = 0;
  int  i = 0;
  while (adress < 2048) {
    for (int n = 0; n <= 3; ++n) {
      for (int a = 0; a <= 3; ++a) {
        data = (eepromArray[i][n] >> ((3 - a) * 8)) & 0x000000ff;
        EEPROM.write(adress + a, data);
      }
      adress = adress + 4;
    }
    ++i;
  }
}

//********************************************************
//
// Save data-pair for later usage
//
//********************************************************
void save(int l) {
  everything[l][0] = z;
  everything[l][1] = angle;
}
```

Comment: Are you never resetting `loopnumber` to 0 once it gets greater than 2559?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop(), you increment repeatedly loopnumber without ever resetting it. You should at the very least replace

```
loopnumber++ ;
```

with

```
loopnumber = (loopnumber+1)%2560 ;
```

Otherwise, when loopnumber becomes >= 2560, your save() function will begin writing outside the 'everything' array and overwriting whatever is written in the adjacent positions of memory.

Comment: You mean `loopnumber = (loopnumber+1)%2560`. What you wrote is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Edgar Bonet : You seem to be right. I fixed the code accordingly.